# How to show selected value from database in dropdown using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, select, dropdown, laravel-5.5, selectedvalue

I want to show selected value from database into dropdown list on page load.

My controller index function is :

```
public function index()
{ 
 $country_data =DB::table('country')->select('country_id','country_name')->get();
$profile_data= DB::table('profiles')->select('*')->where('id',$user_id)->first();
return view('profile_update',compact('profile_data','country_data'));
}
```

Column name in database for height is :Height

My dropdown in profile_update.blade.php is

```
<select class="select4" name="country" id="country">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
 @foreach($country_data as $country)
<option value="{{$country->country_id}}" {{$country_data->country == $country->country_id  ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$country->country_name}}</option>
 @endforeach</select>
```

Comment: Something along the lines of `<option value="5 Feet" @if($profile_data['Height'] == '5 Feet') selected @endif >5 Feet </option>` And repeat for the other options.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a example of how I do this:

```
<select class="js-states browser-default select2" name="shopping_id" required id="shopping_id">
        <option value="option_select" disabled selected>Shoppings</option>
        @foreach($shoppings as $shopping)
            <option value="{{ $shopping->id }}" {{$company->shopping_id == $shopping->id  ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $shopping->fantasyname}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

Comment: @foreach($country_data as $country)
                                    <option value="{{$country->country_id}}" {{$country_data->country == $country->country_id  ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$country->country_name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach  , this is creating error

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand it fully you will need basics of laravel (MVC),
Let suppose, you have controller. In my case I made a separate table for drop down values.

My Approach --- Separate table for values of drop down, you can try different approach but my explanation was mainly focused on concept.

[image]

---

**Note**: PersonInfo is model, sampleType is model of my drop down values and don't forget to make a route for the controller.

```
ExampleController{

public funtion getValues($id){

/*
I am fetching information of a single row from the database by id and 
then passing it to the view. The $id to the function came from the 
request by your view/form. 
I also fetched the values of drop down from the separate table 
of database and passed it to the exampleView.
*/

$selectedValue=PersonInfo::findOrFail($id);
$sampleType=SampletypePicker::all(); //model for fetching all values of drop down

return view('exampleView',compact('selectedValue','sampleType));

   }
}
```

So, in the above controller I fetched all values and passed it to the ExampleView. Now in your View file you have to work likewise.

**exampleView.blade.php** add the below code

---

```
    <?php $options=$selectedValue->sample_type ?> //note take the value from the database which stored for the individual record and match it with the selected one.
    <select class="form-control" name="test">
              <option>Select Test Type</option>
    @foreach ($sampleType as $value)
             <option value="{{ $value->sample_type }}" {{ ( $value->sample_type == $options) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                {{ $value->sample_type }}
              </option>
     @endforeach
    </select>
```

---

It is one of the best approach when you want to add dynamic values to the drop down. I mean if you want to add more values to the select tag options then this is the best approach.

---

**Another Approach - take the idea**

```
      <?php $months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");   ?>

        <?php $options=$patient_data->month ?>

                @if($patient_data->month)
                <select id="expiry_month" name="month" class="form-control-sm">
@foreach($months as $month)
                     <option value="{{$month}}" {{($month==$options)? 'selected':'' }}>{{$month}}</option>
@endforeach
               </select>

            @endif

                <span class="select-icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i></span>
            </div>
```

**OUTPUT of ABOVE CODE**

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Sarita Sharma show the error(s). Maybe then anyone help you to resolve this problem. Show data in colections in controler - use `dd` e.g.

```
dd($country_data);
dd($profile_data);
```

Do you want to display the country in the view with the appropriate Height value from profile_data?

Ps. How to put the code, please use the formatting code - put the code in `` and use camelCase in value name (maintaining good PSR-1 practice) - it is easier to read code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply if anyone still looking for this, here is the simple way to select items for dropdown from database to blade view

```php
$users = Users::pluck('name', 'id');
$selectedID = 2;
return view('users.edit', compact('id', 'users'));
```

add this in the controller function before rendering the view
and in the blade view, simply use this variable as `foreach` loop as

```php
<select name="user_id" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    @foreach ($users as $key => $value)
    <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ ($key == $selectedID) ? 'selected' : '' }}> 
      {{ $value }} 
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

if you don't want to select all users from DB, you can use `where` condition before `pluck` condition as

```php
$users = Users::where('status', 1)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

works with Laravel 8 and Laravel6