# How to call function for checking selected option in laravel blade.php file?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I create a fuction for checking selected option and I want to call it in the 
  for the selected part.

```
@foreach ($stocks as $stock)
   <option value="{{ $stock->id }}" ..... > {{ $stock->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

for the .... should be the place to call the function that I created but I don't know how to call it. 
I tried :

```
@foreach ($stocks as $stock)
   <option value="{{ $stock->id }}" {{ CheckCombo($stock->id, $product- 
         product_type }} > {{ $stock->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

for the function CheckCombo, it returns 'selected' back.

Comment: to  provide a clear answer please provide more details. Do you want to check what is the inserted value in db and then it to be selected in the view. I s that you want @herryben

Comment: When I click edit, it takes product->product_type and checks with stock->id in the db  and I want it to be selected when it match each other with the function that I created.

Comment: is my answer working. If its working please mark it as a answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop the option values check it with the db value and if it gets a match echo **seleceted**

```
 @foreach ($stocks as $stock)
   <option value="{{ $stock->id }}"  @if( ($stock->id) == ($product-> 
         product_type)) selected @endif > {{ $stock->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It doesn't work. should be the syntax is not properly use in this place. It marks in two different color.

Comment: @HerryBen now check it ``>`` was missing

Comment: Where I can't find it, it seems ok.

Comment: @HerryBen if its working could you please mark my answer as answer

Comment: @HerryBen does it generate a eroor

Comment: @HerryBen check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970020/how-to-show-selected-value-from-database-in-dropdown-using-laravel)

Comment: Ohh it works now thank you, but it seems weird for the syntax highlight.