# How to select an option from Laravel into a select?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm bringing all the data from the database and displaying in inputs for an edit page of my CRUD, but I can't figure out how to select an option based on the data.

With inputs I know that I can just do this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="razao" class="form-label">Nome Empresarial</label>
    <input type="text" name="razao" value="{{$cliente->razao ?? old('razao')}}" class="form-control"  id="razao">
</div>
```

But i can't find anything about select, and how to set an option "selected" based on the data from the database.

The select:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<label for="tipoContribuinteSelectCnpj" class="form-label">Tipo de Contribuição</label>
  <select class="form-control select2-single" name="tipoContribuinteCnpj" id="tipoContribuinteSelectCnpj">
     <option hidden></option>
     <option value="I">ICMS</option>
     <option value="X">Isento</option>
     <option value="N">Não Contribuinte</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The data saved in the database is a single char that corresponds to the value of the option of the select.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show selected value from database in dropdown using Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970020/how-to-show-selected-value-from-database-in-dropdown-using-laravel)

Comment: Not really, since that answer is based on build the options and if it matches then it selects, mine is selecting an option on an already built select.

Comment: @Mathias you have a foreach loop with option element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it looks stupid, this is how i did in case you came here from google:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
     <label for="tipoContribuinteSelectCnpj" class="form-label">Tipo de Contribuição</label>
     <select class="form-control select2-single" name="tipoContribuinteCnpj" id="tipoContribuinteSelectCnpj">
          <option hidden></option>
          <option value="I" @if($cliente->tipoContribuinteCnpj == "I") selected @endif>ICMS</option>
          <option value="X" @if($cliente->tipoContribuinteCnpj == "X") selected @endif>Isento</option>
          <option value="N" @if($cliente->tipoContribuinteCnpj == "N") selected @endif>Não Contribuinte</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
<option value="I" {{ $cliente->tipoContribuinteCnpj == 'I' ? 'selected' : '' }}>ICMS</option>
```

Comment: Didn't work, but I've already solved the problem, thanks for your help.