# How to set default value in select dropdown option in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel-5.8

Controller:

```
public $leave_applicable_genders = [
    "1" => "Both",
    "2" => "Male",
    "3" => "Female",
]; 

public function create()
{
    $leavetype = new HrLeaveType();
    
    return view('leave.leave_types.create')
            ->with('leavetype', $leavetype)
            ->with('leave_applicable_genders', $this->leave_applicable_genders);
}
```

view:

```
     <td width="15%">                    
          <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Select Applicable Gender" tabindex="1" name="leave_applicable_gender[]">
               @foreach($leave_applicable_genders as $k => $leave_applicable_gender)
                   <option value="{{$k}}" @if(old("leave_applicable_gender") == "$k") selected @endif>{{$leave_applicable_gender}}</option>
               @endforeach                                         
           </select>
     </td>
```

1. How do I set the default value of the select dropdown option to 1 (Both)?
2. The old() helper is not working. How do I rectify this?

Thanks

Comment: [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970020/how-to-show-selected-value-from-database-in-dropdown-using-laravel)

Comment: you must pass a default value from controller function and check it through condition

Comment: `old` will re-select the value that the user previously selected if e.g. there was a validation error. If you want a default if the `old` value is not present you'd need an additional check

Answer (score 0):

For number 1 - by default it will be selected as it's the first element in `leave_applicable_gender` array.

For number 2 - you can try this

```
@foreach($leave_applicable_genders as $k => $leave_applicable_gender)
     <option value="{{ $k }}" {{ in_array($k, old("leave_applicable_gender") ?? []) ? 'selected' : ''  }}>{{ $leave_applicable_gender }}</option>
@endforeach
```

**Edited Answer**

Why you need to make this select input as multiple select. User only need to select on option so my suggestion would be

```
<select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Select Applicable Gender" tabindex="1" name="leave_applicable_gender">
    @foreach($leave_applicable_genders as $k => $leave_applicable_gender)
        <option value="{{$k}}" {{ old("leave_applicable_gender") == $k ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$leave_applicable_gender}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Also, first selected option will be `both`.

Comment: For number, when I submitted the old() makes everything to be 1 (Both) on the view page

Answer (score 0):

If you pass second argument to `old()` function it will be returned by default. So you can do following:

```
    <td width="15%">                    
        <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Select Applicable Gender" tabindex="1" name="leave_applicable_gender[]">
            @php($val = old('leave_applicable_gender', [1])) {{-- 1 for 'Both' --}}
            @foreach($leave_applicable_genders as $k => $leave_applicable_gender)
                <option value="{{$k}}" @if(in_array($k,$val)) selected="" @endif>{{$leave_applicable_gender}}</option>
            @endforeach                                         
        </select>
    </td>
```

> By setting value `old()` function doesn't run on every `foreach` iteration

Comment: When I submitted the old() makes everything to be 2 (Female) on the view page