# How to get selected data from dropdown button retrieve from database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hye,

I want to get dropdown selected data.
For your information, my dropdown data is from my database. I already retrieve data from database and put it inside my dropdown.
Right now, I want to make validation. If user key in all information and forgot to key in 1 column data, the dropdown part should get the previous selected data right? So here are my coding, I still can get the previous selected data.

```
<div>
    <x-label for="pizzatype" :value="__('Choose pizza type:')" />
    <select name="pizzatype" id="pizzatype">
        <option selected disabled>Please choose</option>
        @foreach ($pizzainfo as $pizzaitem)
            <option value="{{ old('$pizzaitem->name') }}">{{ $pizzaitem->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

[image: example]

All dropdown button should get the selected previous button...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `value="{{ old('pizzatype') }}"` ? I think it is.

Comment: @MajharulIslam i want to retrieve the dropdown data from my database. If i do your way, the data will not retrieve from the database, i already try it just now

Comment: try `<option value="{{$pizzaitem->name == $pizzaitem->name  ? 'selected' : '' }}" {{ $pizzaitem->name }}</option>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970020/how-to-show-selected-value-from-database-in-dropdown-using-laravel

Comment: Still did not retrieve data from database. My coding already retrieve the data for dropdown value from database. but the issues is i did not the previous selected value.

Comment: And this pizzainfo you retrieve is a model that have a relation with customer model right? this validation you are trying to do is on create or in edit?

Comment: @Prospero its inside my create method.. act, its inside my controller not my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the problem is that you are trying to get an old() value that does not exist...
the quick fix is :

```
<select name="pizzatype" id="pizzatype">
    <option @if(!old('pizzatype')) selected @endif disabled>Please choose</option>
    @foreach ($pizzainfo as $pizzaitem)
        <option @if(old('pizzatype') == $pizzaitem->name) selected @endif value="{{ $pizzaitem->name }}">{{ $pizzaitem->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```